# Auto maintanence for Windows 8 will not stay disabled

Tags: windows-8, scheduled-tasks, maintenance

It is imperative that I disable auto maintenance and do it manually because I need access to my PC at odd hours. I thought I had disabled it by going to `Schedule Task > Task Scheduler > Microsoft > Windows > Task Scheduler` and then disabled everything for auto maintenance, only to have it auto maintenance itself when I was in the middle of transferring files that I had been doing for over an hour that I now have to do all over again.

If someone can tell me, preferably remove and delete auto maintenance permanently, or tell me how to disable it so it stays disabled and not ruining more work like it has already done?

Answer (score 2):

If you click on "Start" and type "Maintenance" You will get an option called "Perform Recommended Maintenance Task Automatically". Just change the time to the time you are quite sure you won't be accessing the PC. By default it is set to 2AM.

If you REALLY want to disable it (not recommended), I found a guide here:
http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/34374-automatic-maintenance-enable-disable-windows-8-a.html

Which basically go under "Task Scheduler" and go under \Microsoft\Windows\TaskScheduler and choose "Disable" under "Regular Maintenance" (Not Recommended).